# Timestamp function not showing values for 24 hr format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert the string datatype to timestamp datatype in scala data frame. By using the to_timestamp function I can achieve the results, but it's showing the results only for <12 hrs and its showing null for >12 hrs

```
scala> val df_date = df.withColumn("Date_New",to_timestamp(col("date"),"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"))

scala> df_date.select("date","date_new").show(5)

Date column format MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKy1f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the the date format with 24 hour you should you the date format as HH

```
val df_date = df.withColumn("Date_New",to_timestamp(col("date"),"mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm"))
```

You can check here for all the valid date formats.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html